# Check type a variable

Tags: go, reflection

I'm making a call to [os/Create](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Create) function and want to make sure in one of my test cases that the response is indeed of type *os.File.

Below is my code snippet. Though I made a lot of iterations but the motivation for these lines was [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132848/how-to-get-the-reflect-type-of-an-interface)

```
//somevar -- gets *os.File from a function
var varType *os.File
tpe := reflect.TypeOf(varType).Elem()
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(somevar).Implements(tpe)) // I expect a true or false
```

When I run this code I get a panic:

```
panic: reflect: non-interface type passed to Type.Implements [recovered]
    panic: reflect: non-interface type passed to Type.Implements
```

Please suggest what wrong I'm doing. All I want to check for is - some variable is of type *os.File - yes or no.

Comment: You cannot check if something implements `os.File` because it is not an interface. What is the type of the variable you want to check? Is it an `interface{}`? If so, you can use a type assertion: `file, ok:=intf.(*os.File)`

Comment: The type of the variable I want to check is - *os.File. and I guess its underlying type is a struct. If what I'm doing isn't good, what else could be done to verify something is *os.File type or not? thank you.

Comment: If the type of the variable is `*os.File`, then there is nothing to check. The variable cannot be of any other type, otherwise it would be a compile error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may just be looking for

```golang
var varType *os.File
tpe := reflect.TypeOf(varType).Elem()
fmt.Println(tpe == reflect.TypeOf(somevar).Elem())
```

Comment: This is meaningful only if `somevar` is an interface. Even then, a type-assertion would be much more concise.

Comment: Added a type assertion example. I was just answering the question as OP had it.

Comment: I still miss the point of this question and the answer. The OP mentions a call to os.Create. That cannot return anything other than *os.File. There is nothing to check.

Comment: Yeah on second thought I removed the type assertion example. Because they are clear that it's a concrete type they're testing. They are just being needlessly thorough in testing.

Comment: Test with reflection is pointless as well. What is being tested at runtime is something that will fail at compile time if wrong. If a function is declared to return a concrete type like *os.File then there is no point in testing that, it will not return anything else.

Comment: Thanks folks for your thoughts and replies - appreciate the help.