# Getting reflect.Type of structure

Tags: reflection, go

Is it possible in Go to retrieve reflect.Type from structure itself?

pseudo:

```
type MyStruct struct {
  Name string
}

type := reflect.TypeOf(MyStruct)
```

And is it possible to make slice of that type afterwards?

**Update:**
I am aware of `reflect.TypeOf((*t1)(nil)).Elem()` solution for this problem. I am looking for a better solution to this, as this seems to me pretty unfriendly. I'll try to explain the situation.

While developing 'generic' dataservice above database model, I want to do something like:

```
ds := NewDataService(db.Collection("MyStruct"), MyStruct)
```

where DataService is able to do Find, Insert etc. using that model. Therefore I need to pass the structure so the model can be used correctly (for example with http server).

The second part is needed as `Find` should return slice of found objects.

Because I am using Mongo, there is nothing like *schema* available within *db.Collection*

Comment: possible duplicate of [in golang, is is possible get reflect.Type from the type itself? from name as string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390585/in-golang-is-is-possible-get-reflect-type-from-the-type-itself-from-name-as-st)

Answer (score 1):

For the first part: it is a duplicate of [in golang, is is possible get reflect.Type from the type itself? from name as string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390585/in-golang-is-is-possible-get-reflect-type-from-the-type-itself-from-name-as-st)

For the second part: make slice of that type afterwards:

You can get the [`Type`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) of the slice whose elements' type is what you already have by using [`Type.SliceOf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#SliceOf), and you can use the [`reflect.MakeSlice()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#MakeSlice) function to create a slice of such type. It returns a [`Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value), you can use its [`Value.Interface()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Interface) method to obtain an `interface{}` on which you can use [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) if you need the result as a type of `[]MyStruct`:

```
tt := reflect.TypeOf((*MyStruct)(nil)).Elem()
fmt.Println(tt)

ms := reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.SliceOf(tt), 10, 20).Interface().([]MyStruct)
ms[0].Name="test"
fmt.Println(ms)
```

Output (<kbd>[Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/ec54Hyl_bS)</kbd>):

```
main.MyStruct
[{test} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {}]
```